# Lombok @Data broke for object that is subclass when updating Spring Boot version

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

So basically went from Spring Boot 1.5.10 -> 1.5.15.  Everything fine except for one thing.  I have an object with a parent class that had a @Data annotation on it.  It's now not able to build and saying

-Lombok needs a default constructor in the base class (has 2 constructors but no Lombok constructor annotation)

- java: no suitable constructor found for ErrorResponse(no arguments)
  constructor ErrorResponseObject(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  constructor

Have looked around haven't found anything or I just wasn't able to understand.
Thanks~

Comment: You need to include code. There's no way for us to debug something we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess based on the provided description without looking at the code. 
But have you tried adding **@NoArgsConstructor** annotation to your base class (or simply creating a default no-arg constructor)?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is just the same as irahavoi

```
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Base {
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    class SubClass extends Base{
    }
```